# WCF <413> Request Entity Too Large. </br> The remote server returned an error: <412> Request Entity Too Large

Tags: wcf, iis-7

WCF Streaming transfer mode hosted on IIS and trying to send 2 MB file from a console application but it fails with this error. It works on 3 different servers and NOT one prod server where as all three share the same information.

Is it anything related to SSL on IIS ? what might be problem ?
how to set UploadReadAheadSize Metabase Property in IIS 7.0 ?

IIS 7
Windows Server 2008 64 bit

```
Client:
 <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileStreamingService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

Service:

 <basicHttpBinding> 
        <binding name="HttpStreaming" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <!--<security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>-->
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>    
      </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: What size does your server cut the messages at? Can you try sending a file of 1MB? 1.5MB? What if you raise every 2MB limit in your config (2147483647) to 3 MB

Comment: See [SO: IIS7 - (413) Request Entity Too Large | uploadReadAheadSize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/iis7-413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize)