# The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have a c# application which is giving an error

> The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large

This has hosted in three servers but there is no such large files in the application folder in hosted servers.It gives the same error from different pages but the pages have simple insert functionality .

Is there, any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762311/the-page-was-not-displayed-because-the-request-entity-is-too-large-iis7

Comment: I tried this earlier , but it gives an error and application dose not running well, when I added <serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="value"/> , it fires error. @sorrel Vesper

Comment: The question has been answered on another site as well. I will just copy paste the solution here: Setting uploadReadAheadSize in applicationHost.config file on IIS7.5 would resolve your issue in both cases. you can modify this value directly in applicationhost.config

Comment: For reference: http://forums.asp.net/t/1574804.aspx?HTTPS+413+The+page+was+not+displayed+because+the+request+entity+is+too+large+

Comment: Do you use WCF ? Because: "WCF by default limits messages to 65KB to avoid denial of service attack with large messages".

Comment: Thanks I'm trying. @sorrel vesper

Comment: Yes WCF is there in the application. This is a vast application, and thousands of files and projects folder are there. but the page from where the issue is happening, it's a simple page. @Bartosz Kowalczyk

Comment: Did you check setting uploadReadAheadSize in applicationHost.config file? sorry - I removed rest comment its was about WCF. My bad. Then sorry I don't have any other ideas. <I putted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/iis7-413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize earlier>

Comment: thank you all , this is working.