# WCF content too large Error (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have wcf application, which accept base64 image. It works fine for content length approx upto 69000.
Content lentgh more than 69K throw error. Content length get it from fiddler.

> An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an unexpected
>   response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.

**Service Web.config**

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2097152"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="userServiceBasicHttp" maxBufferPoolSize="2097152" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2097152" maxStringContentLength="2097152" maxArrayLength="2097152" maxBytesPerRead="2097152" maxNameTableCharCount="2097152" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior >
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="customQuotaBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2097152"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <services>
      <service name="ServiceApplication.UserManagement">
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="customQuotaBehavior"  address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="userServiceBasicHttp" contract="Contract.User.IUserManagementContract"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
```

**Client Web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding> 
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IUserManagementContract"  maxBufferPoolSize="2097152" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="999" maxStringContentLength="2097152" maxArrayLength="2097152" maxBytesPerRead="2097152" maxNameTableCharCount="2097152" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="customQuotaBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2097152"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
      <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="customQuotaBehavior" address="http://localhost:3479/UserManagementService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IUserManagementContract"
        contract="UserManagementServiceReference.IUserManagementContract"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IUserManagementContract" />
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Ajax Call**

```
 $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "http://localhost:2583/ApplicationManagement/SaveProfilePhoto",
            data: { 'base64Photo': vData },
            success: function (result) { alert(result); }

        });
```

**Client Method**

```
public string SaveProfilePhoto(string base64Photo)
        {

            UserManagementContractClient client = new UserManagementContractClient();

            string userid = "someuserid";
    //userid -- string
    //PictureType --enum
    //base64Photo --string
            client.UpdateUserPhoto(userid, PictureType.UserPhoto,base64Photo);
            return client.GetImage(userid, PictureType.UserPhoto);
        }
```

Comment: Maybe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763183(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Some worked solutions here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/iis7-413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize