# 413 - Request Entity Too Large IIS and SSL

Tags: iis, ssl, http-status-code-413

I get this error, the moment when I try to send a very large POST call to an Asp.net Web API over SSL.
I am aware of the fenomenon of renegotiation.
My uploadReadAheadSize is set to the max. (2147483647)

Can anybody tell me some options I should try?

Here is are request and response from Chrome dev console:

[image]

I have also tried the following commands without results:

> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Web API"
> -section:system.webServer/ServerRuntime /enabled:"1024000" /commit:apphost
>
> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Web API"
> -section:system.webServer/ServerRuntime /uploadReadAheadSize:"1024000" /commit:apphost

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS7 - (413) Request Entity Too Large | uploadReadAheadSize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/iis7-413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize)

Comment: Your link refers to a problem with a WCF service. Im talking about Web API. Sorry I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @HansElsen were you able to resolve it finally? I'm facing the same issue and have tried almost every options available online.

Comment: @TheGodfather sorry. It has been so long. We have moved on to .NET framework, where this was no longer an issue.

Comment: @HansElsen ok. thank you

Answer (score 9):

IMPORTANT: this answer is available with **HTTPS**

1. Goto configure directory

   C:/Windows/System32/inetsrv/config/
2. Open applicationHost.config file in edit mode.
3. Add this configure for your application

   Example: configure for 1 MB uploading

> ```
> <location path="SiteName" overrideMode="Allow">
>    <system.webServer>
>      ......
>       <serverRuntime enabled="true" uploadReadAheadSize="1024000" />     
>      .....
>    </system.webServer>
> </location>
> ```

4. Restart your site in the IIS

Comment: Is there a method to use it for HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue in Rest WCF Web API and got resolution as mentioned below:

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding 
        maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
        maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
        transferMode="Streamed">
    </binding>  
</webHttpBinding>
```