# Request Entity Too Large WCF issue

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin

i have a simple WCF with a couple of methods, the first is: GetDetails, this method, return me some informations and a couple of images in a byte array (all of this in a XML document), but i have a problem:

when i try to call this method:

```
using (testWCF wcfClient = new testWCF()) { //new testWCF() has no parameter costructors, so i can't use bindings or different endpoint...Why?...anyway
                string ff = wcfClient.GetDetails ("Test");
            }
```

**The debugger throw me a new exception: (413) Request Entity Too Large**

...This is strange, because in the web.config, the configuration seems good:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri=""/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- Quando si distribuisce il progetto della libreria di servizi, è necessario aggiungere il contenuto del file di configurazione al file 
  app.config dell'host. System.Configuration non supporta i file di configurazione delle librerie. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCF">
        <endpoint address="http://10.10.10.1/wcf/WCF.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract=“wcfContract” bindingConfiguration="MyBindingConfig" behaviorConfiguration="SingleFileBehaviour"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBindingConfig" textEncoding="utf-8" openTimeout="00:02:15" closeTimeout="00:02:15" sendTimeout="00:00:15" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SingleFileBehaviour">
          <wsdlExtensions singleFile="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="wsdlExtensions" type="WCFExtrasPlus.Wsdl.WsdlExtensionsConfig, WCFExtrasPlus, Version=2.4.0.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f8633fc5451b43fc"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Please, help me, i'm struggling on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate [IIS7 - (413) Request Entity Too Large | uploadReadAheadSize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/iis7-413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize)

Answer (score 0):

change your configuration as follow :

1. You have to increase the UploadReadAheadSize. (Default size 48kb)
2. Increase maxReceivedMessageSize as below

   ```
   <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
     </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
   ```