# BizTalk Orchestration published WCF service returning "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large."

Tags: wcf, biztalk

I exposed BizTalk Orchestration as a WCF Service and getting "response: (413) Request Entity Too Large." for request larger than 1 MB. I added "bindings" tag to web.config of service as below but no luck.

```
<bindings>
       <basicHttpBinding>
                   <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsync" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
                    </binding>            
      </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I restarted IIS and changed "Max Rec Message Size" setting of BizTalk receive location but no luck.

Comment: <bindings>
    
      <basicHttpBinding>
         
     <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsync" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
         </binding>
         
      </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

Comment: Please add any additional information to the question by using the edit link, rather than in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Cross posted from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/iis7-413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize)

> In my case I had to increase the "Maximum received message size" of the Receive Location in BizTalk. That also has a default value of 64K and so every message was bounced by BizTAlk regardless of what I configured in my web.config

Comment: Note: Not marking this question as a duplicate as the question was not BizTalk specific.

Comment: Have you also looked at the message size settings in IIS?