# Request Entity Too Large Making Ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, json

Here is my problem, on Button Click I call a Jquery function which should execute the code below. Now this executes ok in some instances when the count value is 30996 or around this range. I added the count just to know what the maximum data length should be. However when length increases to 72000 I get an error which reads Request Entity Too Large. What am trying to achieve is to loop through textboxes in a repeater capture their value and save the information.

I looked through some links which advice to increase maxJasonLength, but if the default length is 102400 my data length is still less than the default, why am I still getting this error?

```
$(".inputfield").each(function () {
    // if ($(this).val() != "") {
    csvData = csvData + $(this).attr('id') + " = " + $(this).val() + ",";
    //  }
});

//Check csvData Length
var count = csvData.length;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost/WebMethod",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({"csvData": csvData}),

    success: function (data) {
        alert("Data was saved." + "length is :" + count);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        alert("ERROR " + errorThrown + "length is :" + count);
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that the data gets expanded in the JSON.stringify call.

Comment: you could try putting the max size of int datatype - 2147483647 on maxJasonLength property

Comment: I have alternated between <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"></jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions> and <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="2147483644" /> in the <appsetting> section yet still getting the error

Comment: SOLVED! from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/iis7-413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize. Thanks