# IIS7 - (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-7, soapui

I have a service that converts xml to xslt and sends email. When i am trying to invoke this service with large xml it is prompting 413 Request Entity Too Large. I have tried changing uploadReadAheadSize to 2147483647 and it prompts the same error. Can anyone please help me with this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS7 - (413) Request Entity Too Large | uploadReadAheadSize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/iis7-413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize)

Comment: <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">

Comment: Waqas, i have tried everything in that article but nothing is working out for me.