# error (413) request entity too larg

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I tried to send parameter from client to server with AJAX in ASP.NET but I met with this error. IIS version 8.5 .

my web config:

> ```
> <configuration>
>   <system.web>
>     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
>     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"  
>                  maxRequestLength="10000000" 
>                  executionTimeout="3600" 
>                  maxQueryStringLength="1000000"
>                  maxUrlLength="1048576"
>                  appRequestQueueLimit="50000"
>                  enable="true"
>                  enableHeaderChecking="true"
>                  minFreeThreads="8"
>                  minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
>                  relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="false"   
>                  />      
>     <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
>     <globalization
>       fileEncoding="utf-8"
>       requestEncoding="utf-8"
>       responseEncoding="utf-8"
>       culture="en-US"
>       uiCulture="fa-IR"
>     />
>   </system.web>
>  <system.webServer>
>    <security>
>      <requestFiltering>
>          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" maxQueryString="2147483647" maxUrl="2147483647" />
>      </requestFiltering>
>    </security>   
>  </system.webServer> 
> </configuration>
> ```

Friends who's the solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/iis7-413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize

Comment: What was the "parameter" ? Was it a file ? If so, how large ? What was *the error* ? More info please  :)

Comment: tnx @JeremyKern. i added them. but the problem is not solved.

Comment: tnx @sh1rts. my parameter is a large string. for example : length = 2000 . just for send comment, i want to use them

Answer (score 0):

this is my ajax code:

> ```
> var param_data = "pnumber_post=" + pnumber_post + ""
>                                  + "&text_box_comment="+ text_box_comment+""
>                                  + "&part=" + part + ""
>                                  + "&page=" + page_english_persian + "";
> http_req_post_comment.open("post", "post_comment_all.aspx", true);
> http_req_post_comment.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
> http_req_post_comment.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", param_data.length);
> http_req_post_comment.send(param_data);
> ```

- pnumber_post.length = 5.
- text_box_comment.length = 2000.
- part.length = 5.
- page.length = 5.

Total strings used 2015.
Sometimes when I click a few buttons short time to save the comment, the comment will be saved. But the ratio is 1 to 500.

Comment: Hi Behrad; still need more information. Can you post the server-side code (the target of the AJAX post) and - most importantly - what the error was ?

Answer (score 0):

my customer server manager told me that you need to add:

> ```
> <configuration> 
>    <system.web.extensions>
>        <scripting>
>            <webServices>
>                <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
>            </webServices>
>        </scripting>
>    </system.web.extensions>
> </configuration>
> ```

but, when i add up this code to configration file and when a parameter reaches 6,000... i meet (414 error).