# wcf .net 4.6 iis 7.5 413 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am having problems calling a wcf service from an asp.net application / console application. The error I am getting is ***"The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large."***

Both web.config and app.config have the following lines:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCLService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
    <endpoint address="http://[server]/[projectname].wcfservice/WCLService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWCLService" contract="wclSvc.IWCLService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCLService" />
    </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

This is the web.config of the wcf service itself:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <configuration>
      <appSettings>
       <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
       <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="104857600" targetFramework="4.6" />
       <customErrors mode="Off" />
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
       <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
         </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
       </behaviors>
       <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
       </protocolMapping>    
       <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
       <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".svc" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>
        <handlers>
         <add name="svc-integrated" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler" resourceType="File" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </handlers>
        <security>
         <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
         </requestFiltering>
        </security>
     </system.webServer>

    </configuration>
```

Comment: Please provide more information, i.e. at a minimum the specific error (message) you get. "I am having problems" is a little too generic to act upon.

Comment: Hi Christian, "The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large."

Comment: How big is your request.  Try using fiddler to see the message being sent.

Comment: Hello J Man, this is what I get from Fiddler: Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      147,850  (headers:379; body:147,471)
Bytes Received:  200  (headers:200; body:0)

Comment: Please share the web.config of wcf service as such

Comment: meanwhile, try to consume a helloworld operation and see if its working.

Comment: Hi Houssam, please see whole web.config of WCF Service:

Comment: Hi Houssam, it works with small data, but when I try to pass long text somewhere around 19K characters it fails :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the read ahead byte setting.  Check out the answer to a similar issue:

[IIS7 - (413) Request Entity Too Large | uploadReadAheadSize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15699677/487215)

If you find [Tom P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2223655/tom-p)'s or another's answer has helped you, be sure to vote up his/her answer.  Giving credit where credit is due.