# Sending JSON to a C# WCF-service results in : Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, json, web-services, wcf

I have been looking around and checked several answers but I still keep running into the same problem.

I have a WCF-service which receives data as JSON and then processes it.
I have a console-application which calls this service.
But I keep running into the same problem: 'The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.

In my console-application config I have :

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPaymentBehaviorService"  allowCookies="true"
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:50068/PaymentBehaviorService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPaymentBehaviorService"
            contract="PaymentBehaviorServiceService.IPaymentBehaviorService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IPaymentBehaviorService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

My server-config :

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

One line in the data that is being sent, looks like :

```
{ \"ReqId\":\"79\",\"TaxNbr\":\"889638963\",\"Amount\":\"29,4\",\"Invoice\":\"10/2330\",\"InvDate\":\"19/04/2018 0:00:00\",\"ExpDate\":\"19/04/2018 0:00:00\" }
```

I can only send about 450 of those lines in one request. 
I need to raise that number of lines to something like 1500 or even more.
How can I do that?

I have found a lot of similar questions but none that gave me a solution.

Comment: You're changing the client config. You need to change the server config.

Comment: I don't unserstand what you mean. Can you please explain?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize#10123764

Comment: I have added the bindings as they appear in my server-config. Can you tell me what I need to change?

Comment: I think you need to add a binding declaration: `<basicHttpsBinding><binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760"></binding></basicHttpsBinding>`

Comment: @BartSchelkens - Are you using IIS ?

Comment: @Prany: I'm using IISExpress.

Comment: then this might help - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jiruss/2007/04/13/http-413-request-entity-too-large-cant-upload-large-files-using-iis6/

Answer (score 0):

Have you played around with TransferMode attribute in the basicHttpBinding; setting the mode to "streaming"

Comment: If I include the TransferMode-attribute, I get that message that the attribute is not allowed.