# http 413 request entity too large error fix

Tags: c#, .net

I have written a web service that accpets incoming file data. For some reason it is not accepting data above 40- 50 kb and when i send a request trhough SOap UI i get the follwing error http 413 request entity too large.. Can anyone suggest a fix?

I have arleady increased the size of the query and other strings to the maximum  in the app.config. As you can see below in the code.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>

<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" maxRequestLength="102400"/><pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
```

```
<services>

  <service name="CRM_Recruiting.SendLeadsFromAPI">

    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILeadsFromAPI" contract="CRM_Recruiting.ISendLeadsFromAPI"/>

  </service>

</services>

<bindings>

  <basicHttpBinding>

    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_SendLeadsFromAPI" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">

      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>

    </binding>

    <binding name="PublishHSB"/>

    <binding name="OnboardingServicesBinding"/>
```

how can i fix this to be able to accept a larger size of file data
?

Comment: Hi, could you post a minimum reproducible example of your code?

Comment: <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISendLeadsFromAPI" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="PublishHSB"/>
        <binding name="OnboardingServicesBinding"/>

Comment: See answer with 12 points at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(413) Request Entity Too Large | uploadReadAheadSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize)