# Getting 413 request too large in WCF windows hosted service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-hosting

Currently I am working on wcf service which is hosted as windows service,I am not getting any error when running it in debugging mode,but when I host it as an windows service,I am getting error msg as "413 request entity too large"I had also mentioned maxRequestLengh ="1048576" and maxAllowedContentlength="1048576" which is more than sufficient for my call my WCF service accepts single string of 107kb.if anyone have any solution please share.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you set `maxReceivedMessageSize` in your binding, you provided too little information to know the clear reason, you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize) to find the solution.

Comment: Yes @LanHuang I all ready set maxReceivedMessageSize

Comment: Did you check the answer provided by the link? Make sure the web.config and app.config are configured the same, maybe you can provide the code of the config file to help you solve the problem better.